# What is killing my usb-c ports?

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-c

The past year I've had 4 laptops which usb-c ports has stopped working. Two laptops has been HP elitebooks, one Lenovo yoga 920 and one Apple macbook air m1.

This has all happened within a year and I start to doubt that this is a coincidence.

However I need help to find the common culprint here. I've multiple usb-c chargers and cables in my house. All from different computer chargers, phone cables and usb-c to monitor cables.

I think I have something in my house killing my computers. How can I start to figure this out?

Comment: Consider the possibility that it's a specific device that you're connecting at the other end of those cables.

Comment: Hard to tell from here without testing the devices. USB-C is particularly subject to damage because specs state it can handle *high* power, i.e., 5A @ 20VDC, 100 W. Could be a power supply with too much, or badly filtered voltage, could be a device drawing too much current...

Comment: Not sure if this is still a topic with USB-C but I had an USB-A devices like a monitor which illegally provided current on the USB upstream port (as far as I know this is not allowed on older auasB and for USB-C only if both connected devices have agreed). Luckily this caused never any damage or problem, but such it could have damaged the port on PC side. Also consider factors like the power grid which could pass through high voltages because of surges or similar events.